# ¿GET y POST en botón de Formulario?

Tags: php, formularios, post, get

Estoy recibiendo por get 5 variables en un formulario con input button:

```
<?php
$valorI1 = $_GET['valorI1'];
$valorI2 = $_GET['valorI2'];
$valorI3 = $_GET['valorI3'];
$valorI4 = $_GET['valorI4'];
$valorI5 = $_GET['valorI5'];
?>

<form action="nuevaPagina.php" method="post">
 <div class="container"><br>
                <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label class="container"><b>Si</b>
                            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="seleccion" value="00">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="container"><b>No</b>
                            <input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="11">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="container"><b>No sé</b>
                            <input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="22">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  <?php echo "<a href='nuevaPagina.php?valorI1=$valorI1&valorI2=$valorI2&valorI3=$valorI3&valorI4=$valorI4&valorI5=$valorI5' role='button' type='submit'>ENVIAR</a>";?>
</form>
```

**Me gustaría envíar a la siguiente página de mi formulario las 5 variables recibídas por GET al igual que la selección de radio button del formulario pero no se si sea valido lo que estoy haciendo en el botón.**

```
 <?php echo "<a href='nuevaPagina.php?valorI1=$valorI1&valorI2=$valorI2&valorI3=$valorI3&valorI4=$valorI4&valorI5=$valorI5' role='button' type='submit'>ENVIAR</a>";?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar justo como lo necesitaba.

Sólo la añadí al `action` del `form` las variables que necesitaba enviar y en el `method` seguí utilizando `POST`:

```
<form action="nuevaPagina.php?valorI1=$valorI1&valorI2=$valorI2&valorI3=$valorI3&
valorI4=$valorI4&valorI5=$valorI5'" method="post">

                        <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="seleccion" value="00">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="container"><b>No</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="11">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="container"><b>No sé</b>
                        <input type="radio" name="seleccion" value="22">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
</form>
```

Y en tanto al botón lo dejé normal y de tipo `submit` para que pudiera enviar lo de la selección del radio:

```
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer no es correcto y dudo mucho que funcione, pero puedes intentar dos opciones:

**1- Enviar los datos por GET:** Solo los agregas en la etiqueta de formulario y se enviarían en la misma forma que lo estás intentando por enlace:

```
<form method="post" action="nuevaPagina.php?<?php echo "valorI1=$valorI1&valorI2=$valorI2&valorI3=$valorI3&valorI4=$valorI4&valorI5=$valorI5"; ?>">
```

**2- Enviar los datos por POST:** Solo agrégalos como campos ocultos y se enviarán con el resto del formulario:

```
<form method="post" action="nuevaPagina.php">
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"valorI$i\" value=\"{$_GET['valorI' . $i]}\">
}
?>
```

Para cualquiera de las dos opciones:

```
<!-- Aquí el resto del formulario y, finalmente, botón submit -->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ENVIAR">
```